# Docker - nginx port map other than 80 not work

Tags: docker

I am a new guy to get into Docker. I have a problem, in my host machine, I ran a nginx container `docker run -d --name mynginx -p 80:80 nginx`, and I can access 80 port on my host machine.[Acess 80 port works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KICGs.png)

But if I map another port other than 80 on host machine, then it seems not work. `docker run -d --name mynginx -p 80:8888 nginx`.[Acess 8888 port not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwBZw.png)

Someone can tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: You are using it the wrong way around: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports. *format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort* so your command should be `-p 8888:80`

Answer (score 1):

The order is host:container.

So in your case, this is what you need:

```
docker run -d --name mynginx -p 8888:80: nginx
```